# The output gives the same result

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, cypher

Im trying to run this code but it gives the same output:
What I’m trying to do is that ask the user to enter text to be encrypted. Then enter the key he wants to use to encrypt either  128, 192, or 256. But when I test it whenever I enter anything it gives the same output  :(
this is the method i'm trying to call

```
package test;

public class MARS {
    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] in,byte[] key){
        K = expandKey(key);
        int lenght=0;
        byte[] padding = new byte[1];
        int i;
        lenght = 16 - in.length % 16;
        padding = new byte[lenght];
        padding[0] = (byte) 0x80;

        for (i = 1; i < lenght; i++)
            padding[i] = 0;

        byte[] tmp = new byte[in.length + lenght];
        byte[] bloc = new byte[16];

        int count = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < in.length + lenght; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && i % 16 == 0) {
                bloc = encryptBloc(bloc);
                System.arraycopy(bloc, 0, tmp, i - 16, bloc.length);
            }
            if (i < in.length)
                bloc[i % 16] = in[i];
            else{
                bloc[i % 16] = padding[count % 16];
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(bloc.length == 16){
            bloc = encryptBloc(bloc);
            System.arraycopy(bloc, 0, tmp, i - 16, bloc.length);
        }

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

this is the class of calling method

```
package test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Call {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] array = "going to encrypt".getBytes();
        byte[] key = "the key you want to use".getBytes();
        byte[] encryptBloc = MARS.encrypt(array,key);
        BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String plainText = userInput.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Text that you want to Encrypt: " + plainText);

        BufferedReader ke = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String kee = userInput.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter The Key you want to use to encrypt this message: " + new String(key));
        System.out.println("plain Text: "+ plainText);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + new String(encryptBloc));
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if MARS would have been defined, you always encrypt static data (array, key)...

Comment: Sorry guys I was edditing the code i just add the code that I'm trying to call from other class. well this is part of it where the method i'm trying to call

Comment: Static data means that Can't ask the user to add his own text that he want's to add? in other words static means always the same output?

Comment: Whatever user enters while running your program only changes one output line where you repeat it back to him. Otherwise your program is completely deterministic.

Comment: Aha I see now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just flat out makes very little sense. You're getting the bytes of string literals as the plaintext and the key, and you're (essentially) ignoring the user input. You're also creating multiple input streams that you're not using, and prompting for user input at weird times.

Here's what it should look like:

```
// Create input reader
BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

// Prompt, then wait and get user input for the plaintext 
System.out.println("Enter Text that you want to encrypt:");
String plainText = userInput.readLine();

// Prompt, then wait and get user input for the key
System.out.println("Enter the key:");
String key = userInput.readLine();

// Actually encrypt it
byte[] encrypted = MARS.encrypt(plainText.getBytes(), key.getBytes());

// Print encrypted and unencrypted
System.out.println("Plain text: " + plainText);
System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + new String(encrypted));
```

Comment: that's really Amazing thank you for organizing my code. actually i wasn't paying attention to organizing the code because later I will take this code to GUI design. anyways thank you that makes sense now I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MissA Sure. Happy to help.